# How to Unbuild Packages

Tags: ros, bloom-release

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I want to take some packages off the build farm. I tried moving the package.xmls to package.xml.NOBUILD (as I've seen done) but after I prepare my catkin release, the packages won't bloom-release.

```
==> git push --tags
Total 0 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0)
To https://github.com/brown-release/nasa_r2_simulator_release
 * [new tag]         debian/ros-hydro-r2-gazebo_0.5.4-1_precise -> debian/ros-hydro-r2-gazebo_0.5.4-1_precise
 * [new tag]         debian/ros-hydro-r2-gazebo_0.5.4-1_quantal -> debian/ros-hydro-r2-gazebo_0.5.4-1_quantal
 * [new tag]         debian/ros-hydro-r2-gazebo_0.5.4-1_raring -> debian/ros-hydro-r2-gazebo_0.5.4-1_raring
 * [new tag]         release/hydro/r2_gazebo/0.5.4-1 -> release/hydro/r2_gazebo/0.5.4-1
 ! [rejected]        debian/ros-hydro-gazebo-gripper_0.5.3-1_precise -> debian/ros-hydro-gazebo-gripper_0.5.3-1_precise (already exists)
 ! [rejected]        debian/ros-hydro-gazebo-gripper_0.5.3-1_quantal -> debian/ros-hydro-gazebo-gripper_0.5.3-1_quantal (already exists)
 ! [rejected]        debian/ros-hydro-gazebo-gripper_0.5.3-1_raring -> debian/ros-hydro-gazebo-gripper_0.5.3-1_raring (already exists)
 etc....
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/113776/how-to-unbuild-packages/) by [David Lu](https://answers.ros.org/users/19/david-lu/) on ROS Answers with karma: 10932 on 2013-12-29

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

To remove something from the buildfarm remove it from the rosdistro.

To tell bloom to ignore it in the future you can use a hydro.ignored in your gbp repo: https://github.com/ros-gbp/ros_comm-release

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2013-12-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [David Lu](https://answers.ros.org/users/19/david-lu/) on 2013-12-29**:
What if I only want to remove some of the packages from the "stack"?

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2013-12-29**:
Only remove those packages from the rosdistro file. They are listed explicitly https://github.com/ros/rosdistro/blob/master/hydro/release.yaml#L1229 in the release.yaml